# Drawing diagrams in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, visualization, diagram

Could anyone tell me what the best way visualize data in a diagram in Swift on iOS?

I've heart about SpriteKit and SceneKit but aren't they rather used for games? If possible it should even be possible to scroll trough the diagram and to highlight certain values by tapping.

I'm looking forward to getting a response.

Comment: Consider also the option to have a WebView with the diagram in your SWIDFT application: where I work they've just published a [simple guide](http://keylines.com/network-visualization/build-a-graph-visualization-ipad-application) for a SWIFT -> JS diagram example. Feel free to take inspiration from it.